# Laravel Mail::later in error handling

Tags: email, laravel

I am working with Laravel error handling and want to send email from App::error when exception occurs.

Following code is working and I get emails

```
$data = array('exception' => $exception,'ip'=>$ip,'host'=>$host,'url'=>$url);
$details=['server'=>$server];
Mail::later(10,'emails.exception', $data, function($message) use($details)
{
    $message->from('xxxx@xxxx.com');
    $message->to('xxxx@xxxx.com')->subject('Error on '.$details['server']);

});
```

However, when I change from Mail::send to Mail::later(20, I get following error when exception occures

Error in exception handler: Array to string conversion (View: /app/views/emails/exception.blade.php) in /app/storage/views/1c8e0883061171a30b7f85d86c83370d:8

My email template is as follows

```
Client: {{$ip}}
Host: {{$host}}
URL: {{$url}}
Exception:
{{$exception}} - This is where the error is
```

Comment: What's the `$server` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Mail::later`, Laravel depends on [jeremeamia/super_closure](https://github.com/jeremeamia/super_closure) to serialize PHP [Closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) objects. I suspect your exception is being serialized into an array.

Since you're using `$exception` exclusively as a string (not an object), you can fix the problem by stringifying the exception *before* passing it to `Mail::later` by using typecasting:

```
$data = array('exception' => (string) $exception, 'ip'=> $ip, 'host'=> $host, 'url'=> $url);
```

Comment: This solved my problem, but I noticed that even with Mail::later, I get 7 seconds response time vs If I disable mail part I get it back in under a second!

Comment: Never mind, I do not have any queue implemented. I think once I implement beanstalkd, it will handle sending later